# Skipping words from a list that contain non-alpha characters in R

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I was wondering what would be the fastest and most robust way to skip all words from a long list of words that contain non-alpha characters?

Input should look like this:

```
words = c('one', 'two', 'three,', 'four', '.five', 'others\'', 'ma-ny')
```

and resulting, new list should then be:

```
newWords = c('one', 'two', 'four')
```

`gsub()` or something from the **tidyverse** and `stringr` package? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `grep` from base R as akun is suggesting or you can the package `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(words, "^[:alpha:]+$")
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `grep` by specifying the pattern to have only one or more alphabets (`[[:alpha:]]+`) from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("^[[:alpha:]]+$", words, value = TRUE)
#[1] "one"  "two"  "four"
```